# Why is there a voltage drop across a superconducting inductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

If there is no electric field inside a perfect conductor, then why is there a potential difference across an (superconducting) inductor?

Answer (score 6):

When there is a changing current through the inductor, there is a changing magnetic flux threading the inductor coils and, thus, there is an induced electric field through the conductor and an associated emf.

If the inductor is constructed from a perfect conductor, there can be no *net* electric field inside the conductor.

In order to cancel the induced electric field within the conductor, the charge distribution within the conductor must be such that the *conservative* field, due to the charge distribution, cancels the *induced* electric field inside the conductor.

This charge distribution produces a conservative electric field *outside* the conductor and thus, there is an associated potential difference across the inductor.

Note that there is only a potential difference when the inductor current is *changing*; there is no potential difference when the inductor current is constant.

Comment: So that means there is an electric field inside the measuring device but not inside the inductor (assuming R=0)?

Comment: @Armadillomon, I don't follow your reasoning.

Comment: Suppose you have an RL circuit with AC voltage source. If the inductor is superconducting, then the net electric field inside is 0. But if you connect a voltmeter across the inductor, it will show a potential difference. A voltmeter shows something if there's a current passing through it and since it has non-zero resistance (preferably very high), it means that if there's a current passing through the voltmeter, then there's also an electric field inside it. Does that mean there is an electric field inside the voltmeter, even though there is none inside the inductor?

Comment: @Armadillomon, yes - there may be non-zero electric field outside, but it vanishes inside the conductor.